# Css fix/freeze row and column border line missing

Tags: html, css

I wanted to freeze/fix the table first row and first 2 columns. Below code works, only that when scrolling left to right, the first 2 columns left and right borner are gone. Any commend?

css and html

```
  <html>
    <center><h1>testing</h1></center>
      <head><meta name="xx" content="HTML" />
      <title>testing</title>
      <body bgcolor=aliceblue>
      <font color=brown><b>
    <style type="text/css">
    table.sample {
      border-width: thin thin thin thin;
      border-spacing: 4px;
      border-style: ridge ridge ridge ridge;
      border-color: black black black black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      background-color: lightyellow;
      text-align: center;
      word-break: break-all;
      overflow: scroll;
      width: 400;
      table-layout:fixed;
    }
    table.sample th {
      border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
      padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
      border-style: ridge ridge ridge ridge;
      border-color: 1px solid black;
      background-color: aqua;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
      text-align: center;
      word-break: break-all;
    }
    table.sample td {
      border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
      padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
      border-style: ridge ridge ridge ridge;
      border-color: black black black black;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
      text-align: center;
      word-break: break-all;
    }
    thead th {
      top: 0;
      position: sticky;
      z-index: 20;
      background-color: aqua;
      border-color: 1px solid black;
    }
    .category_col {
      left: 0;
      position: sticky;
      background-color: lightyellow;
      border-color: 1px solid black;
      border-left-color: 1px solid black;
    }
    .stage_col {
      left: 150;
      position: sticky;
      background-color: lightyellow;
      border-color: 1px solid black;
      border-left-color: 1px solid black;
    
    }
    .fixed_header {
      z-index: 50;
    }
    </style>
    
    <table class="sample">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th width="150" class="category_col fixed_header">Category</th>
            <th width="150" class="stage_col fixed_header"><font color=brown>Stages </font></th> 
            <th width="350"> a </th> 
            <th width="350"> b </th> 
            <th width="350"> c </th> 
            <th width="350"> d </th> 
            <th width="350"> e </th> 
            <th width="350"> f </th> 
            <th width="350"> g </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="category_col" scope="row" rowspan="8"><b>Info</b></td>
            <td class="stage_col" scope="row"><b>Stage 1</b>
                <td>x</td>
                <td>x</td>
                <td>x</td>
                <td>x</td>
                <td>x</td>
                <td>x</td>
                <td>x</td>
        </tr>
                
        <tr>
            <td class="stage_col" scope="row"><b>Stage2</b>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
            
        <tr>
            <td class="stage_col" scope="row"><b>Stage3</b>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
            
        <tr>
            <td class="stage_col" scope="row"><b>Stage4</b>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
            
        <tr>
            <td class="stage_col" scope="row"><b>Stage5</b>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
            
        <tr>
            <td class="stage_col" scope="row"><b>Stage6</b>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td class="stage_col" scope="row"><b>Stage7</b>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="stage_col" scope="row"><b>Stage8</b>
            <td>y</td>
            <td>y</td>
            <td>y</td>
            <td>y</td>
            <td>y</td>
            <td>y</td>
            <td>y</td>
        </tr> 
    </table> <br><br>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your document has HTML structural errors and wrongly ordered and unclosed tags. Fix that first.

Comment: @RenevanderLende, could you give more detailed which order is wrong? Sorry I am new to this

Comment: Your markup up has errors, please fix that first. https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options